# Docker network communication issue

Tags: windows, docker, networking, server

I am new to this docker, i have started running the container services in 2016 server. When i run iis image "Docker run -it -p 80:80 microsoft/iis its started successfully. but when try to access the iis sample page its not loading via local host. but i can access the docker host name and ip address of the host.  I know it is limitation in WINNAT but when i try to access from my another machine using the ip address of the host ( ex. htt://192.168.1.5/ form another machine on the same n/w) iis sample page is not accessible. Can anybody help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the localhost at http://localhost:80

Comment: yes, but it not works.. because there is a limitation in WINNAT  as per MS.  but its not happening even i tried from other host still page is not opening